# Go one iteration step back in Array.prototype.map

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to go one iteration step backwards in JavaScript's `Array.prototype.map` or `Array.prototype.forEach`? i.e. if the current iteration index is, for instance, 2, can we go back to index 1? Keeping in mind that we can achieve this with a normal `for-loop` by decrementing `i`, is there a way to do this with `map`?

Comment: [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *access* the previous element in `.map` by using the third parameter provided to the callback:

```js
const input = [1, 2, 3];

const output = input.map((num, i, arr) => {
  console.log('last num was ' + arr[i - 1] + ', current num is ' + num);
  return num + 1;
});
```

But there's no way to *assign* to the previous element in the new mapped array, since the previous iteration's `.map` callback has already run and had a value returned.

One method that might accomplish what you're looking for is, instead of looking from the next element *backwards*, look from the current element *forwards*, and return the new mapped value based on that:

```js
const input = [1, 2, 3];

const output = input.map((num, i, arr) => {
  console.log('next num is ' + arr[i + 1] + ', current num is ' + num);
  return num + (arr[i + 1] || 0);
});
console.log(output);
```